# SQL query case when without else or do nothing?

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, case-when

Supposed I have some sample data in `table_name_a` as below:

```
    code     val_a  val_b    remark   date
   ------------------------------------------
1   00001    500    0.1      111      20191108
2   00001    1000   0.2      222      20191109
3   00002    200    0.1      111      20191110
4   00002    400    0.3      222      20191111
5   00001    200    0.2      333      20191112
6   00001    400    0.1      444      20191113
```

My expected output as below:

```
        code    111_a  111_b 222_a 222_b 333_a ....
       --------------------------------------------
    1   00001    500    ..    ..     ..   ..
```

And below SQL query will contain `0` value which covered the correct values, does it possible to query without `Else` or do nothing?

```
SELECT code, date,
       CASE WHEN t.remark='111' THEN t.val_a ELSE 0 END 111_a,
       CASE WHEN t.remark='111' THEN t.val_b ELSE 0 END 111_b,
       CASE WHEN t.remark='222' THEN t.val_a ELSE 0 END 222_a,
       CASE WHEN t.remark='222' THEN t.val_b ELSE 0 END 222_b,
       CASE WHEN t.remark='333' THEN t.val_a ELSE 0 END 333_a,
       CASE WHEN t.remark='333' THEN t.val_b ELSE 0 END 333_b,
       CASE WHEN t.remark='444' THEN t.val_a ELSE 0 END 444_a,
       CASE WHEN t.remark='444' THEN t.val_b ELSE 0 END 444_b,
FROM table_name_a t
```

Comment: Do you want all 00001 values in one row? Complete the expected result, so it matches the sample table data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `MAX` with pivoting logic here, though you are on the right track:

```
SELECT
    code,
    MAX(CASE WHEN remark = '111' THEN val_a END) 111_a,
    MAX(CASE WHEN remark = '111' THEN val_b END) 111_b,
    MAX(CASE WHEN remark = '222' THEN val_a END) 222_a,
    MAX(CASE WHEN remark = '222' THEN val_b END) 222_b,
    MAX(CASE WHEN remark = '333' THEN val_a END) 333_a,
    MAX(CASE WHEN remark = '333' THEN val_b END) 333_b,
    MAX(CASE WHEN remark = '444' THEN val_a END) 444_a,
    MAX(CASE WHEN remark = '444' THEN val_b END) 444_b
FROM table_name_a
GROUP BY
    code;
```

The logic here works because for each group of records belonging to a single code, we take the maximum value only under certain conditions, in this case for certain values of remark.  Should the condition be false, then the `CASE` expressions would return `NULL`, which would then be ignored by `MAX`.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks so so so much, you really saved my day,  thank you☕️☕️

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the `date` column is not needed?

Comment: @Moudiz I guess not; if date is expected, then the OP would also have to show proper data for that.

Comment: @Moudiz Hey, it needs `date` column in my example

Comment: Hi Tim, other data without data will be saved into `None` or `nan`, can I save them with `0`?

Comment: Yes, use `ELSE 0` as the else condition.  For example: `MAX(CASE WHEN remark = '111' THEN val_a ELSE 0 END)`

Comment: Thanks so much for your patience ☕️☕️